# How to create a tsv file on Google Storage Transfer

Tags: hash, google-cloud-storage, md5

Google provide a great documentation for their cloud services, but unfortunately nobody can understand the content.
Their explanation always jumping and leave people with no clue to accomplish even a simple task.

Creating tsv file should be a simple task.

I tried to follow everything in this page [Creating a URL List](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list) but stuck with "unknown error" log.
Unknown error means I never know what I am doing wrong.

They gave example downloaded file md5-test a string "Storage Transfer MD5 Test" => BfnRTwvHpofMOn2Pq7EVyQ==

I can successfully verify the md5-test file with

```
`openssl md5 -binary md5-test | openssl enc -base64`
```

to get hash "BfnRTwvHpofMOn2Pq7EVyQ=="

Is it mean the hash for "Storage Transfer MD5 Test" is "BfnRTwvHpofMOn2Pq7EVyQ==" ?

They gave different string in their example code:

> TsvHttpData-1.0
>   https://example.com/buckets/obj1      1357      wHENa08V36iPYAsOa2JAdw==
>   https://example.com/buckets/obj2      2468      R9acAaveoPd2y8nniLUYbw==

It is not match, and leave me with no clue which object should be encoded?
Why don't they just gave the download file content the same with the example code?

What string will generate "wHENa08V36iPYAsOa2JAdw==" ?

I have tried to put every part of the example code in the md5-test file and run `openssl md5 -binary md5-test | openssl enc -base64` but can not get that example hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The md5-test file is used to verify that you can generate md5 hashes correctly. Since you're getting the correct md5 hash `BfnRTwvHpofMOn2Pq7EVyQ==` from this file, you're all set for generating Base64-encoded MD5 hashes.

Now you'll need to generate one for each file you'd like to include in your TSV file by running locally the following command:

`openssl md5 -binary <your_file_name> | openssl enc -base64`

which will give you a new Base64-encoded MD5 hash for each file. You can then upload the files to their final destination and create the TSV file accordingly. To take the example provided in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list), and let's say you'd like to include the md5-test file in your URL list, the resulting TSV file would look like this:

> TsvHttpData-1.0
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/md5-test/md5-test 26 BfnRTwvHpofMOn2Pq7EVyQ==
>   https://example.com/buckets/obj1 1357 wHENa08V36iPYAsOa2JAdw==
>   https://example.com/buckets/obj2 2468 R9acAaveoPd2y8nniLUYbw==

Comment: Thanks for pointed out the right direction.    I lose because in the only example codes provided it gave non existing url while likely generate real hashes.    I can generate the tsv file correctly, now come another problem, the transfered file status complete but give 0 bytes. [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zb3dRDgtmAXqRVeeonrwLH7EM1amtdzc).    I get the file size using #wc -c < myfile.zip   559378601  In my tsv file :  TsvHttpData-1.0  
https://example.com/myfile.zip 559378601  0yLbmTUd8ubfxG+hfKJj+w==    Any clue?

Comment: Second attemp where I put the same tsv file in google bucket, give me failed status with this error. [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R_Xye7U898mKpr6xqlXbuvs6z26RZPGF)

Comment: 559378601 bytes correspond to ~559.37MB, however in your last screenshot I can see a failed transfer for a 533.47MB. If the size does not match, the object will not be transferred. Can you check in case there's an error or typo here?

Comment: How do I get the right file size using linux debian command line?  I use "wc -c <  myfile.zip" to get the size in bytes. Can you suggest some other lines? There is no info about that in the documentation page.